# Facebook JS+PHP SDK returns exception This authorization code has expired

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

We're using the JS & PHP SDK to create a custom login process on our web app. Everything was working fine until we found an issue with some users that couldn't login back (by firing FB.login()).

After some research we figured out the users were returning to the website **after a long time** and the SDK was giving an exception: "**This authorization code has expired.**".

We're using extended tokens and these are valid for 60 days and, on expiry, a new token must be issued. This is made automatically by taking the user to the login process.

If this is correct, why are we getting the exception even after calling FB.login() everytime the user tries to login with Facebook into our website?

**The login process:**

The login process is a mix of JS and an AJAX call to log the user on Facebook and then on the website.

1- User enters the website

2- User clicks the "Login with Facebook" button

3- Trigger FB.login() and call the PHP scripts via AJAX

PHP Code being executed via AJAX:

```
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();

try {
    $FBsession = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // $ex->getMessage() == 'This authorization code has expired.' 
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}
```

*I can't assure this, and i don't know if it has something to do, but most of the cases are mobile users which accessed our website and logged into m.facebook.com the first time they were asked to grant access to our app.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

where facebook is sending the user after the log in action ( I assume is where you have the code pasted below) try:

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

Comment: And be sure you have completed in Settings/Advanced for your app the 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' field.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment. I'm using the JS SDK to process the login and then the PHP SDK to grab the cookie set by JS via **FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper** and then do the internal login process on the website.
**FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper** is the only way to access the cookie set by JS on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get in touch with a mobile device where i could reproduce the issue.

After debugging the browser I can see there are two fbsr_ cookies set. One pointing to ".domain.com" (note the period in front of the domain name) and the other one to "domain.com".
After deleting the one under "domain.com" the exception was gone and I was able to log in correctly.

The PHP SDK checks for:

```
$_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $this->appId]
```

and it was picking the "wrong" one.
Now I wonder, how did this happen?

Comment: I don't know why you have this problem, but facebook id saying something like this:
"It's important to note that on first access, or if a session has since expired, these methods will operate on data that is one request-cycle stale. You will likely want to make an Ajax request when the login state changes in the Facebook SDK for JavaScript. Information about that here: FB.event.subscribe."

Why you don't use PHP sdk and for the login flow ? You need just to show the login url... user press it... and you don't need to take an extended token.

I hope you will find a way to get over. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who use v3 for some reason.

In the function `getAccessTokenFromCode` the result of `_oauthRequest` might be in the JSON format, not URL format. In the code the result is transforming with `parse_str()` and for that reason to not return the correct `access_token`.